# webpack not bundling with babel-loader and react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, babeljs, babel-loader

I am following along with a relatively older tutorial (from 2014) on RGR. I had to use an updated version of React, Webpack, and Babel so there are some differences. Everything has been working thus far except when I tried to compile JSX into webpack, it is giving me a build error.

```
ERROR in ./public/js/app.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (7:15)

5 | class Hello extends React.Component {
6 |     render() {
7 |         return <h3>Hello Webpack!</h3>;
  |                ^
8 |     }
9 | }
```

10 |

Below is my React file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h3>Hello Webpack!</h3>;
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

and this is my webpack.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./public/js/app.js",
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public",
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {test: /\.js$/, 
            loader: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
}
}
```

Also, here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "rgrjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a collection of educational resources about React, GraphQL, and Relay",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/krisxcrash/rgr-stack.git"
  },
  "author": "kristine martin",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/krisxcrash/rgr-stack/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/krisxcrash/rgr-stack#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1"
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it is not reading the `<h3>` after return and causing an error when webpack is trying to bundle?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping <h3>Hello Webpack!</h3>; in brackets like ' return { <h3>Hello Webpack!</h3>; }' ?

Comment: I believe you need to configure your babel-loader to look for jsx. This blog post from Twilio may be helpful: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html. Specifically, the part about "Bundling everything with Webpack"

Comment: @Dream_Cap I just tried wrapping the html in brackets and it did not work.

Comment: @DerekHopper let me try that - tbd!

Comment: @DerekHopper so I have everything bundled. Updated the /\.jsx?$/, and it still doesn't seem to work. I tried changing the filename to a .jsx but it had issues when re-bundling the webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some presets:

First do npm install:

```
npm install  babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react --save-dev
```

Also make a .babelrc in your root project directory, and include this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015","react"]
}
```

Also in your loaders section of webpack config, include this for jsx:

```
{ test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ['babel-loader'] }
```